# В чем разница между словами "подвижник" и "поборник"?

Tags: лексикон, выбор-слова

## Подвижник

В словаре Ефремовой определяется как

> Самоотверженный труженик.

а в словаре Ожегова:

> Человек, героически принявший на себя тяжёлый труд или лишения ради
> достижения высокой цели

Пример использования: *Подвижник науки.*

## Поборник

В словаре Ефремовой определяется так:

> Ревностный защитник, сторонник кого-либо, чего-либо.

в словаре Ожегова так:

> Защитник, сторонник чего-н.

Пример использования: *Поборник мира*.

## Вопрос

Для меня эти слова очень близкие по смыслу. В чем разница между ними? Если возможно, мне был хотелось увидеть примеры, в которых можно использовать только одно из слов, но не оба, либо в которых одно из слов явно предпочтительнее другого.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Подвижник* means an ascetic person, willing to abandon the joys of life for a greater purpose.

*Поборник* means "a champion", like in "a champion of justice", a person who fights for his beliefs.

*Подвижник* does not require an object, *поборник* does (*поборник справедливости, поборник правды*)

> - Вопрос же вовсе не в том; вопрос в том, может ли средний врач, ― не **подвижник**, а обыкновенный работник, ― прожить в деревне врачебным трудом. *[В. В. Вересаев. Записки врача (1895-1900)]*
> - Он был вдохновенный оратор и рьяный **поборник** эмансипации в тяжелые времена сурового режима. *[Ф. И. Буслаев. Мои воспоминания (1897)]*

You cannot swap the words in these examples.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. About the examples. As I see, we can't use "поборник" in the first example because it would require an object, which the first example lacks, and also "не подвижник" has a connotation of not being ascetic. As regards the second example, "поборник" is used because there is no implication of him abandoning the joys of the life, which would be implied if we used the word "подвижник". Correct?

Comment: @ovgolovin: absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `подвижник` works on something, whereas `поборник` fights for something.